# Which language is decidable

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Just been at the Math-exam.
One question I was really unsure about, was this question - so I didn't answer it, as you get minus point if the answer is wrong.
Does somebody know, what the right answer is for this problem - it made me crazy in the exam.

> [image]

Comment: How do you indicate that none of them are decidable?

Comment: I think the last option is not avaliable, because infinity is not a option on turing.

Comment: No body who knows anything about it?

Comment: The Halting Problem reduces to each of the last three languages, while the first one has a finite upper bound as noted by Brian in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not my field, but I think that the first one is decidable. You feed $w$ to a Turing machine that both runs a universal Turing machine on the input $w$ and records all system configurations of that simulation of the ATM $w$ until either the simulated machine uses more than four million tape cells, or it repeats a configuration. In the first case it rejects $w$, and in the second case it accepts $w$. Since there are only finitely many system configurations using at most four million tape cells, this is possible.